# force vb14 / visual studio 2015 to retain old behavior for implicit conversions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

This code behaves differently in VB12 vs VB14.
How can we force the vb compiler to keep the old behavior? The new behavior throws an unhandled excetion because of the new call to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions::ToDate(string)` in the VB14 IL version.

Exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDate(String Value)
   at VBConsoleApplication1.Module1.Main() in c:\Module1.vb:line 7
```

Source Code

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim dt As New DateTime
        dt = vbNullString
        Console.WriteLine(dt)
        Console.WriteLine("Any Key")
        Console.ReadKey(False)

    End Sub

End Module
```

VB12 IL

```
.method public static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       49 (0x31)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime dt,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime VB$t_date$N0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldloca.s   dt
  IL_0003:  initobj    [mscorlib]System.DateTime
  IL_0009:  ldloca.s   dt
  IL_000b:  initobj    [mscorlib]System.DateTime
  IL_0011:  ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  box        [mscorlib]System.DateTime
  IL_0017:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
  IL_001c:  nop
  IL_001d:  ldstr      "Any Key"
  IL_0022:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0027:  nop
  IL_0028:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0029:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey(bool)
  IL_002e:  pop
  IL_002f:  nop
  IL_0030:  ret
} // end of method Module1::Main
```

VB14 IL

```
.method public static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       47 (0x2f)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime dt)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldloca.s   dt
  IL_0003:  initobj    [mscorlib]System.DateTime
  IL_0009:  ldnull
  IL_000a:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions::ToDate(string)
  IL_000f:  stloc.0
  IL_0010:  ldloc.0
  IL_0011:  box        [mscorlib]System.DateTime
  IL_0016:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
  IL_001b:  nop
  IL_001c:  ldstr      "Any Key"
  IL_0021:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0026:  nop
  IL_0027:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0028:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey(bool)
  IL_002d:  pop
  IL_002e:  ret
} // end of method Module1::Main
```

Comment: just out of curosity what is actually different? Does it give a different value?

Comment: @Jeremy the VB14 version throws an exception because of the call to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions::ToDate(string)`. I modified the question to clearer

Comment: changing code is not an option? In the old version what was the value of dt after this assignment?

Comment: one more thing...I have both vs 2008 and vs 2013 installed on my machine, and both of them throw an exception when running this code...

Comment: @Jeremy wrong source code. Sorry. Assigning the date variable explicitly is what we are doing. There is no intermediate variable.

Comment: I'll go back to whether you can change code or not. IMO vbNullstring is a holdover from vb6, and if you want to clear out a datetime variable, assign it to Nothing rather than vbNullString. If you are trying to just initiailize the variable, don't bother, because it has a default value when instantiated.

Comment: @Jeremy - thanks for your input. I'm familiar with all these implications and the associated holdovers from Classic VB. If changes are made, they have to be tested. The issue here isn't whether we CAN change the code. The issue is with whether the VB14 compiler can retain backwards compatibility.

Comment: I think you've just proven that it is not backwards compatible. It seems to me like the new version of VB actually treats vbNullString like a String. At best it is an intentional doing by the VB team, at worst it is a bug that should be reported on MS connect because of breaking behavior between versions. If you are upgrading to a new version, I'd expect that you are doing comprehensive testing anyways, so why not take the opportunity to remove a holdover from over a decade ago :)

Comment: @jeremy - the visual studio and .net connect forum is secure. I'll have to wait and see if they let me join before I can submit it there

Comment: go here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback

Comment: @Jeremy thanks. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1635455
btw. my name is Jeremy too :)

Comment: [This is a known problem](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2780), they decided not to fix it.  Not so sure that was a wise choice, it is going to break a lot of code that dates from the VB6 days.  Especially in interop code, vbNullString was ab/used pretty heavily.  I sympathize with the decision though, replicating quirky behavior in a complete compiler rewrite is a major headache.

Comment: @HansPassant wins. Please convert your question to an answer so I can mark as correct. Do you know where the list of breaking changes is ?